# Lookup table dilemma

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem on how to return a list of organizations based on it's type.  Let me describe the schema:

Look up table for Organization Types

```
TypeOfOrganization (table)
-- Id (Guid)[PK]
-- Type (varchar)
```

Example Data

```
Id                                   Type                
------------------------------------ --------------------
0C54DECC-6A7B-463F-A160-20F3F270473E Company Location    
B07BE7A9-E569-43F7-B6D9-8A9B19F6D35C Mail Center         
BEA6E923-2170-40B0-9F54-8B6458DB75FD Client              
EBC8C254-FE87-4241-BA37-AD0B1FF5C370 Counsel             
F5EEEF8D-454D-430E-815E-CDFF942D28A0 Company             
5FDC2CD5-A0E9-4656-96C1-F365E67A1E42 Bank                
B4D25CD7-D695-4A6D-9E81-FDD673BDD2A3 Vendor
```

Join table for Orginization to OrganizationTypes

```
OrganizationType (table)
-- Id (Guid)[PK]
-- OrganizationId (Guid)
-- TypeOfOrganizationId (Guid)
```

Example Data

```
Id                                   OrganizationId                       TypeOfOrganizationId
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------
FECEC824-C5F4-41F8-9F5D-3236371A51B0 448FED23-393C-4019-87AE-0ED64764DFB1 F5EEEF8D-454D-430E-815E-CDFF942D28A0 (Company)
CEA03A1B-9E5F-49A5-BE04-9871A41986CF BEAAA39B-71BD-4F12-A570-FD71FEFD8503 F5EEEF8D-454D-430E-815E-CDFF942D28A0 (Company)
00998ACA-22D2-49D3-B2A2-CE2F3231B38A 1F87F1C5-44B9-4C60-9C38-001975229193 BEA6E923-2170-40B0-9F54-8B6458DB75FD (Client)
50CABBD2-CD55-4781-8BF3-83715216BF1A 6C8DC3B8-5A65-446E-A02B-02354FEDB3E3 BEA6E923-2170-40B0-9F54-8B6458DB75FD (Client)
5E60C5BF-4A36-4546-A3A9-818A1BC6E31B A315020C-268B-4F22-866C-034ACFC22A53 BEA6E923-2170-40B0-9F54-8B6458DB75FD (Client)
56629DFC-A78E-4092-8390-2ABFB21E6CB8 1BF7DAB9-7126-4DC8-A089-0169A52E9FF3 B4D25CD7-D695-4A6D-9E81-FDD673BDD2A3 (Vendor)
280AAE16-1732-44F7-8B8B-0357C5DAD2C4 7FC1BF63-6069-471D-85FC-09F4F5068DD2 B4D25CD7-D695-4A6D-9E81-FDD673BDD2A3 (Vendor)
... and more
```

FYI, the last column with the organization type names does not exist in this table, I just put them there to better visualize the structure.

Organization Table

```
Organization (table)
-- Id (Guid) [PK]
-- Name (varchar)
```

Example Data

```
Id                                   Organization   
------------------------------------ ---------------
1F87F1C5-44B9-4C60-9C38-001975229193 Client A
6C8DC3B8-5A65-446E-A02B-02354FEDB3E3 Client B
A315020C-268B-4F22-866C-034ACFC22A53 Client C
448FED23-393C-4019-87AE-0ED64764DFB1 Company A
BEAAA39B-71BD-4F12-A570-FD71FEFD8503 Company B
1BF7DAB9-7126-4DC8-A089-0169A52E9FF3 Vendor A
7FC1BF63-6069-471D-85FC-09F4F5068DD2 Vendor B
00674C8A-34B9-46EF-B591-0C5EFBA4EB2B Vendor C
... and more
```

My question is, what is the best way of querying for an organization of a particular type without having to use the Constants class?

Example:

- I want to get a list of all organizations that are clients.
- I want to get a list of all organizations that are vendors.
- I want to get a list of all organizations that are companies.

Currently, my Linq query in my ASP.NET WebApi project to get a list of Vendors, looks like this:

```
var vendors = context.Organizations
    .Where(v => v.OrganizationTypes
       .Any(t => t.TypeOfOrganizationId == Constants.TypeOfOrganization_Vendor);
```

This is the Constants class:

```
public static class Constants
{
    //TypeOfOrganization lookup table
    public static Guid TypeOfOrganization_Client = Guid.Parse("BEA6E923-2170-40B0-9F54-8B6458DB75FD");
    public static Guid TypeOfOrganization_Company = Guid.Parse("F5EEEF8D-454D-430E-815E-CDFF942D28A0");
    public static Guid TypeOfOrganization_Bank = Guid.Parse("5fdc2cd5-a0e9-4656-96c1-f365e67a1e42");
    public static Guid TypeOfOrganization_Location = Guid.Parse("0c54decc-6a7b-463f-a160-20f3f270473e");
    public static Guid TypeOfOrganization_Counsel = Guid.Parse("ebc8c254-fe87-4241-ba37-ad0b1ff5c370");
    public static Guid TypeOfOrganization_Vendor = Guid.Parse("b4d25cd7-d695-4a6d-9e81-fdd673bdd2a3");       
}
```

I realize this is not the best way of handling this, but at the moment I can't figure out a reliable way of doing this.

Comment: You could try EF Inheritance, but your tables in the database will get weird. Overall with your schema you need to know the ID of type. I would consider flipping your query though. Find the type you want and all associated organizations.

Comment: Why do you have a join table from `Organizations` to `OrganizationTypes`? Is it possible for an `Orginization` to have more than one type? What is the purpose of the `OrginizationTypes` table?

Comment: @Blast_dan - finding the type I want is the issue. I can't query for the type based on the Id, since I don't originally know it, and I can't query on the name since that's something the administrator could change at any time.

Comment: @NetMage - that's actually a good question.  I'll have to ask the DBA.

Comment: On a side question, does your DBA know not to use those GUIDs as the clustering key for those tables?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Guid is not the best choice for the PK of `TypeOfOrganization`. Since the organization types are not arbitrary but have special meanings within the application, you could formulate them as `enum`.

```
public enum OrgType
{
    None = 0,
    CompanyLocation = 1,
    MailCenter = 2,
    Client = 3,
    Counsel = 4,
    Company = 5,
    Bank = 6,
    Vendor = 7
}
```

And query with

```
var vendors = context.Organizations
    .Where(v => v.OrganizationTypes
        .Any(t => t.TypeOfOrganizationId == OrgType.Vendor);
```

---

If you cannot change the primary key, add a new nullable column for known organization types, mapped to the `enum`. Then read known types into a dictionary for the lookup of the Guid by the enum.

```
Dictionary<OrgType, Guid> knownOrgGuids = context.OrganizationTypes
    .Where(t => t.KnownType != null)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.KnownType, t => t.TypeOfOrganizationId);
```

```
Guid vendorGuid = knownOrgGuids[OrgType.Vendor];
var vendors = context.Organizations
    .Where(v => v.OrganizationTypes
        .Any(t => t.TypeOfOrganizationId == orgGuid);
```

Comment: That's an idea, unfortunately, the Type table is something that is maintainable in the UI, so if new records are created, then the enum would have to be updated.  And currently, the DBA requires the use of Guids instead of ints for primary keys.

Comment: Added a variant where the enum is stored in an additional column.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few choices here.

1. Create constants like you are doing. Though, this can feel painful.
2. Select the Id based on the actual name of the type. This is a bit more fragile since the name could be updated.
3. Add another Identifier column that can't change. This could be an int or another name that is a string that isn't allowed to change. e.g. can set the field on create on UI but can't update it. You can even put an index on this column to make it faster.